# How to send a mail from getresponse.com when user submits a form in my website?

Tags: php, email, getresponse

I have a form. When a user submits the form after filling it, I have to send a mail to the user by using getresponse.com and also the user email should be added to my mailing list. I have an account in getresponse.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getresponse` [github](http://github.com/GetResponse/DevZone/tree/master/API/examples/) page has examples of using their API in C#, Javascript, Python, Perl, and PHP.  You don't tell us which language you want to use -- is it none of these?

Comment: And?  What's wrong with the sample at http://github.com/GetResponse/DevZone/blob/master/API/examples/php_synopsis.php ?  (Adding PHP to your tags to attract PHP expects -- I'm not one of those;-).

Comment: bizarrely GetRespone.com seem to have deleted all their sample repos and I can't find them in their API documents either. I guess they hate money.